# How to get console to refresh whenever an integer changes?

Tags: c++, system, c++-chrono

I am making a little program that gets the current time from my time zone (EST) ((also this is either in the wrong time zone or doesn't want to deal with daylight savings time because it adds an extra hour)) and prints it out in console.

I am looking for a way for console to refresh (by whatever means, I am using the tabooed system("cls") for this one) every time the integer I am using for seconds changes.

So every second the console would clear the previously outputted time, then print out the current time.

I am free to get another library if I need to (prefer not to though).

Comment: Use *\r* to return to the start of the line and print the new time, every second.

Answer (score 0):

You need to print the carriage return `\r` character every time you update the value on the console and `flush` the output stream if you print a newline.

For example

```
std::cout << "\rValue 1 ";    /// Output should be of equal no. of chars every time
std::cout << "\rUpdate 1";
std::cout << "\rUpdate 2";
. . .
```

carriage return (`\r`) returns to the first position in the current line instead of going to the next line.

You can flush the output stream by

```
std::cout.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<unistd.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  time_t x,y;
  time(&x);
  cout<<ctime(&x);
  for(;;x++)
    {
      sleep(1);
      cout<<"\r"<<ctime(&x);
    }
}
```

I hope this will suit your needs.

Comment: Why not while(x++) ? it's a more readable way in my opinion